# Symfony 3.0.6 do not see my routes

Tags: php, symfony

I'am newbie starting working with Symfony.

Atm im doing quick tour from official symfony [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_controller.html)... but im stuck with controller!

I'm sure i did same thing as in toutorial yet error occured:
"No route found for "GET /hello/name"

Here's my code:

\src\AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php

```
/**
 * @Route("hello/name{name}", name="hello")
 */
public function helloAction($name)
{
    return $this->render('default/hello.html.twig', array(
        'name'=> $name
    ));
}
```

\app\Resources\views\default\hello.html.twig

```
{%extends 'base.html.twig' %}{% block body %}
<h1>Hi {{name}}! Welcome to Symfony!</h1>{%endblock%}
```

Comment: Is your routes.yml configured to accept annotations routes from DefaultController ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial shows:

```
/**
* @Route("hello/{name}", name="hello")
*/
```

and it works, since the static route part is `hello` followed by a parameter.

You have `@Route("hello/name{name}", name="hello")`

It is not very clear what do you want exactly, if you want to have `/hello/name/xxx`, you should try `@Route("hello/name/{name}", name="hello")`

Comment: I just realized i made dumb mistake. I inserted "name" before "{name}". As i said im a newbie. Thanks for your answer!